# Redirect to newdomain/subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to redirect a sub-directory, to a new domain/subDirectory but I am not getting the redirect to work. 
(ie;) www.oldDomain.co.nz/oldSubDirectory/ to www.newdomain.co.nz/subDirectory/ .

The expression I'm using with no success is:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldDomain\.co\.nz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldSubDirectory/(.*)$ http://newdomain.co.nz/subDirectory/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

I have had some success using the following, but it only goes to the new root directory and not the intended sub-directory. The htaccess is in the root of the oldDomain.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldDirectory(.*) http://newdomain.co.nz/subDirectory$1
```

What do I need to adjust to reach the subDirectory?